# Showing the following bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

[image]

My attempt. I split the inequality into a sum of two parts:

$$\mathbb{P}(S_N-\mu\le{-\delta\mu}) + \mathbb{P}(S_N-\mu\ge{\delta\mu})$$

rearranging to make the LHS of the inequality $S_N$ and applying chernoff bounds I obtained:

$\le(\frac{1}{1+\delta})^{\mu+\mu\delta}e^{\mu\delta}+(\frac{1}{1-\delta})^{\mu-\mu\delta}e^{-\mu\delta}$

but can't to bound this by anything that resembles the bound in the question.

Have I gone completely the wrong direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the generic Chernoff bound, for $s>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(S_N\ge (1+\delta)\mu)&\le e^{-s(1+\delta)\mu}\prod_{i=1}^N\mathsf{E}e^{sX_i} \\
&\le e^{-s(1+\delta)\mu}\prod_{i=1}^N e^{(e^s-1)p_i} \\
&=e^{(e^s-1-s(1+\delta))\mu}
\end{align}
because for $x\in[0,1]$,
$$
e^{sx}\le 1+(e^s-1)x\le e^{(e^s-1)x},
$$
and $\sum_{i=1}^Np_i=\mu$. Finally, optimizing over $s$, one gets
$$
\mathsf{P}(S_N\ge (1+\delta)\mu)\le e^{-(\ln(1+\delta)(1+\delta)-\delta)\mu}\le e^{-c\mu\delta^2}
$$
for some constant $c>0$ ($\because\delta\in (0,1])$. The second bound can be found similarly.