# Prove $\frac{\exp(\delta \mu)}{(\delta +1)^{(\delta +1)\mu}} + \frac{\exp(-\delta \mu)}{(1-\delta)^{(1-\delta) \mu}} \leq 2\exp (-c\mu \delta^2)$

Tags: probability, inequality

When solving an exercise from the book High-Dimensional Probability by Vershynin, I was faced with the task of proving the following inequality
$$\frac{\exp(\delta \mu)}{(\delta +1)^{(\delta +1)\mu}} + \frac{\exp(-\delta \mu)}{(1-\delta)^{(1-\delta)\mu}} \leq 2\exp (-c\mu \delta^2)$$

Where $\delta \in (0,1)$ and $c$ is a constant. Now, I have already proved that

$$
cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \leq e^{-x^2/2}
$$

Is there a way of proving the first inequality by using the one above?

Comment: Are you sure $\delta \in (0,1]$? As then the denominator of the $2$nd term is undefined

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixing the question now.

Comment: Check this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529468/showing-the-following-bound/3529742#3529742)